# Is it possible to turn an ArrayList into a bunch of AsyncTask parameters?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Let's say I have an `AsyncTask` with a signature something like:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
```

And I want to pass a handful of `String` variables to it, plus the elements from some `ArrayList<String>` so that I am executing this AsyncTask like this:

```
new SomeTask().execute(one, two, three, x0, x1, xn); // where  x0 through xn are the elements from some ArrayList.
```

I could of course create a constructor for `SomeTask` that would take an ArrayList and assign it to a member variable and then pass the String variables to the `execute` method, but I wonder if there is something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, the bunch of parameters is a simple String[] Array. So do just this

```
//list is your ArrayList
String [] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
new SomeTask().execute(stringArray );
```

Comment: But the signature of my `AsyncTask` says: `AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>`, will it still let me pass a `String[]`?

Comment: Yeah it will let you! Because the first param in your Asynctask declaration just gives the Type of Object, but do inbackground can get a array of that type